# How to center and hypertext MySQL table

Tags: html, css, mysql

I think I've created some trouble for myself. I managed to link to a DB on MySQL and display my table in a nice format, great. Trouble is I've used a set of code that's a little above my understanding.

Now I'd like to change this table, and the surrounding page. I'd like to center the table and make the last field a hyperlink.

Could someone please either, make this a more simpler table formatting algorithm or change some of the stuff on this so I can see how it works. I'm new to all this both CSS and php - like the function beginchildren  for example to me it doesn't really seem to be doing anything. Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
echo "<table { border: 2px outset grey / darkgray; padding: 1px }
td { border: thin inset grey /darkgray; margin: 1px };'>";


echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>ELE Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Time Stamp</th><th>Log Order</th>
<th>Initials</th><th>Status</th><th>Notes</th><th>Footage</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function __construct($it) {
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:100px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "LifeSaverDB";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM LifeSaver1");
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>


    <?php include('/var/www/html/LifeSaverHTML/Templates/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: you should indeed start with a simpler code, one you understand. fetching data from the database and displaying it like you want to do is somewhat basic so you shouldn't have any issue with that. With the current code identifying the last column will not be easy or at least you may lose the advantage of using a foreach or a custom iterator.

Comment: Thx for the reply Marc I'd almost given up hope. Yeh that's what I was thinking. I'm not completely without programming experience but my degree is EEE so this html stuff is outside my zone. Ok can you help me understand how I could make a web address clickable as part of a field on the database. Oh and any good resources you have. I see you're a php developer.